# Option to close as duplicate of linked question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, close-dialog

**Disclaimer:** This question assumes sufficient familiarity with [the Close dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

In the Close -> Duplicate dialog, when no vote has yet been cast, there is a **list of similar questions**, otherwise there is a **list of possible duplicates**.

Can **linked questions** also show up in the **list of similar questions**?

### Justification + elaboration:

I ask for this since low-rep users often just provide a link to a duplicate or high-rep users may provide a link rather than voting to close if they aren't sure.

I know I can paste the link of the duplicate question in there, but it would be simpler to just click on the correct question.

Now you may ask `"Is pasting a link to a linked question too much effort?"`, to which I respond `"Is pasting a link to a linked question too much effort?"` can be thought of very similar to `"Is pasting a link to a similar question too much effort?"`. There are **already** similar questions, so the only questions left are (1) whether linked questions are often duplicates or (2) whether this change is more effort than it's worth.

To clarify further, I would like something like this:

[image]

Or, explicitly separating "linked" and "similar":

[image]

### Related:

A decent argument can also be made for having **linked questions** also show up in the **list of possible duplicates**, but also against, so I won't ask for that.

Comment: you can post the link of the duplicate question in there, you don't have to selcet one of the suggested duplicates, you can also go view the linked question in another tab

Comment: I actually am not sure what you are suggesting

Comment: you want me to make yr question clearer, can you explain a bit more to me in yr comments

Comment: @Yve See latest edit. I trust the image will clarify it.

Comment: I don't really get it Dukeling, it's like splitting hairs or asking to be spoon fed. It's a site for programming enthusiasts etc, not learning the alphabet

Comment: @Yve Doesn't your argument kind of fall apart when considering that we're given a list of similar questions to simply click on?

Comment: it's not an argument, this is your feature request, you are asking to reinvent the wheel, YES you are reaffirming my position, there is ALREADY a drop down list, for the more pedantic, they can copy and paste.

Comment: What does this mean: "A decent argument can also be made for having linked questions also show up in addition to the possible duplicates, but also against, so I won't ask for that.". This seems to invalidate what I thought this question was asking for

Comment: @RichardTingle As stated in the first paragraph, there are 2 variations of what questions appear in the list - one being a list of similar questions, the other being a list of possible duplicates (depending on whether votes has been cast or not). I'm asking that the list of similar questions be extended to include linked questions as well (and in the last paragraph I refer to adding linked questions to the list of duplicate questions).

Comment: So you're saying you'd like a list of possible duplicates plus: 1 list containing linked questions and similar questions together. You're explicitly not asking for 3 lists: duplicates, linked, similar

Comment: @richard: i assume you don't have experience with the closing dialog? Because it's really not hard ti understand if you have any familiarity with closing duplicates .

Comment: @RichardTingle There are **already** 2 lists: possible duplicates and similar questions. Now I'm asking for similar questions to be extended to include linked questions.

Comment: @Dukeling It makes sense now, it was however confusing because your image showed two seperate lists but you seemed to state that you didn't want that

Comment: @Dukeling "Disclaimer: This question assumes sufficient familiarity with the Close dialog (which you presumably haven't seen if you don't have more than 2999 reputation).", politics Dukeling politics

Comment: @RichardTingle Maybe, but the question doesn't give an introduction to the Close dialog, so someone with less than 3k reputation might have a hard time picturing it, as well as not having dealt with it (obviously), thus also won't have a well-thought-out non-theoretical opinion regarding the matter, based on the day-to-day usage of the dialog. I haven't done a lot of flagging, so I don't know if users with less than 3k reputation are given a very similar dialog.

Comment: @Dukeling More or less identical, I think this feature request would automatically carry over to the flag screen

Comment: @Dukeling Either way this is no longer unclear and I have upvoted it because politics aside it is a good idea

Answer (score 5):

[image]That's what this is for:

You can paste a link to the duplicate question, or the question id.

Comment: Note; this answer was posted to the first version of this question